# gb_events working routing configuration typo3

Tags: routes, typo3, url-routing

I have a TYPO3 v11 instance running with gb_events 11.0.1 installed.

What is a working routing configuration for gb_events
so you can to have nice urls using the path_segment field?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that the routing configuration for this extension is nowhere to be found easily...
(yeah of course, we can write it ourselves...) which I did,
so here you are, a simple example to get you started:

```yaml
    #[...]
    routeEnhancers:
    #[...]
      Events:
        type: Extbase
        extension: GbEvents
        plugin: Main
        defaultController: 'GbEvents::list'
        routes:
          - routePath: '/{gbevents-title}'
            _controller: 'Event::show'
            _arguments:
              gbevents-title: event
        aspects:
          gbevents-title:
            type: PersistedAliasMapper
            tableName: tx_gbevents_domain_model_event
            routeFieldName: path_segment
    #[...]
```

Best regards,
MT